# Is there anything in storm watch service?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I had a bolt to which input file keeps on updating. But I can't take updated content since I am reading the file from `prepare()` method. I want to take updated file without stopping or killing the topology. Is there anything like watch service in Storm to do it? Or any different approach for this?

Comment: How often does your file change?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to your problem is defining a Spout that would periodically check if the file changed. Once it does, it would send a tuple notifying your bolt about a change. The bolt would in turn reload the file. Here are a few hints about implementation:

Topology will contain the new monitoring spout. Your bolt will subscribe to it's stream and to any other stream it needs (bolts can consume multiple streams):

```
topologyBuilder.setSpout("file_checking_spout", new FileCheckingSpout(myMonitoredFile));
topologyBuilder.setBolt("my_bolt", new MyBolt())
    .shuffleGrouping("file_checking_spout")
    .shuffleGrouping("whatever other grouping you need");
```

Spout will do the monitoring. If there is only one file to monitor, you can just emit empty tuples as notification:

```
public class FileCheckingSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if (fileChanged()) { // check e.g. file modified timestamp
            collector.emit(new Values());
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields());
    }
    // ...
}
```

Your bolt will now have to accept the notifications about file reload. It can distinguish notification tuples e.g. using `tuple.getSourceComponent()`:

```
class MyBolt implements IRichBolt {
    @Override 
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        if ("file_checking_spout".equals(tuple.getSourceComponent())) {
             reloadFile();
             return;
        }
        // normal processing
    }
    //...
}
```

You could also simply check if the file changed in your bolt's `nextTuple()`. The way described above is more "the Storm way" as it separates concerns and reloading is not dependent on any other streams.

PS: Naturally, this will work as long as the file is accessible from both spout and bolt, i.e., if you are running in a cluster, it should be on a shared file system.

Comment: +1 very nice answer. An alternative to the spout worth mentioning is to use Tick Tuples if you want it to be time based (ex: reload file every 5 minutes). http://kitmenke.com/blog/2014/08/04/tick-tuples-within-storm/ (disclaimer: my blog)